# Restricted access to s3 using temporary credentials

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to get temporary credentials with specific permission that my app can use to working with S3 over API.
The problem is that policy variable ${aws:userid} don't work in my case.

Steps for reproduce:

Create policy for allow all s3 actions to user-specific folder.

```
policy = AWS::STS::Policy.new(version: '2012-10-17')
policy.allow({
  actions: ["s3:*"],
  resources: ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/folder/${aws:userid}/*"]
})
```

Get temporary credential with previous policy.

```
sts = AWS::STS.new(:access_key_id => 'ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY',
                   :secret_access_key => 'ADMIN_SECRET_KEY')
session = sts.new_federated_session("custom_user", policy: policy)
```

Now `session` return all required credential params and `user_id` like `811395474237:custom_user`.

And i expect that this user_id will be in ${aws:userid}, but it don't so.

```
s3u = AWS::S3.new(session.credentials)
bucket = s3u.buckets['my-bucket']
file = bucket.objects.create("folder/#{session.user_id}/user.txt", 'test file', :acl => :public_read)
```

This return me `Access Deny` error.

Which should be in ${aws:userid} when use credentials from `sts.new_federated_session("custom_user", policy: policy)`?